# remote: GitLab is not responding

Tags: gitlab

Добрый день.

Мой локальный Gitlab находится за Nginx.
Настройку делал по статье - https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation

После отключения Nginx-а Gitlaba и убирания Gitlab-a за обычный Nginx не могу работать с репозиториями моего локального Gitlab-а по http, по ssh всё работает прекрасно.
Веб интерфейс самого Gitlab-а работает.

При клонировании репозитория выводит вот что:

```
git clone http://репозиторий temp
Cloning into 'temp'...
remote: GitLab is not responding
fatal: unable to access 'http://репозиторий': The requested URL 
returned error: 502
```

Вывод команды gitlab-ctl status

```
run: gitaly: (pid 17745) 235168s; run: log: (pid 29668) 10880694s
run: gitlab-monitor: (pid 17755) 235167s; run: log: (pid 29871) 10880676s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 17775) 235167s; run: log: (pid 29734) 10880688s
run: logrotate: (pid 12645) 1164s; run: log: (pid 29783) 10880684s
run: node-exporter: (pid 17791) 235166s; run: log: (pid 29854) 10880678s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 17797) 235166s; run: log: (pid 29952) 10880662s
run: postgresql: (pid 17803) 235165s; run: log: (pid 29478) 10880742s
run: prometheus: (pid 17811) 235165s; run: log: (pid 29907) 10880668s
run: redis: (pid 17821) 235164s; run: log: (pid 29411) 10880748s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 17825) 235164s; run: log: (pid 29890) 10880670s
run: sidekiq: (pid 17830) 235164s; run: log: (pid 29648) 10880700s
```

При попытке клонирования репозитория по http получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
2018-01-23_12:17:02.38917 2018/01/23 16:17:02 error: GET "": 
badgateway: failed after 0s: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: 
connection refused
```

Спасибо.

Comment: а зайти на сам gitlab получается (браузером)? Скорее всего гитлабу стало плохо. А ssh часть работает достаточно отдельно.

Comment: Я тупанул, извиняюсь. Gitlab у меня локально развёрнут. Я не про Gitlab.com говорю

Comment: ну так кто же не понимает, что это локальный гитлаб. Иначе уже в новостях начало проскакивать бы.

Comment: т.е. получается мне нужно настроить https, т.к. по http я не смогу работать?

Comment: на веб интерфейс могу зайти. в том то и дело что всё вроде работает, только работа с репозиториями из консоли по http не работает

Comment: используйте ssh. А веб интерфейс по https работает?

Comment: у меня веб интерфейс по http, https нет. я ещё не настраивал

Comment: gitlab-workhorse упал, видимо

Comment: в вопрос добавил вывод команды gitlab-ctl status

Answer (score 0):

У гитлаба нет http, только https, возможно из-за этого, плюс в ubuntu у меня было пару раз что-то подобное из-за того, что криво копировался url на сайте и между clone и самой ссылкой нужно было удалить пробелы и ручками поставить заново. Гитлаб сейчас не лежит - проверил, так что проблема у вас

Comment: Я тупанул, извиняюсь. Gitlab у меня локально развёрнут. Я не про Gitlab.com говорю